Question about Caratheodory's Theorem applied on unbounded sets
Caratheodory's Theorem: Suppose $D$ is a bounded simply connected region in the plane and $\partial D$ is a simple closed curve. Let $\phi : D \to \mathbb{D}$ be a conformal equivalence. Then $\phi$ extends to a homeomorphism of $\overline{D}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Let $Q^+ = \big\{ z = x+iy : y > 0, \, 0 < x < 1, \, \big|z-\frac{1}{2}\big| > \frac{1}{2} \big\}$.
The Riemann Mapping Theorem shows that there exists a confromal map $h : Q^+ \to \mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane. Caratheodory's Theorem shows that $h$ extends to a homeomorphism of the extended closure of $Q^+$, that is $\overline{Q^+} \cup \{ \infty \}$ onto $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$.
I don't understand how the Caratheodory's Theorem works for that unbounded set $Q^+$. It says that "In the proof we will be applying results that were proved for bounded open sets, such as Caratheodory's Theorem ,to certain unbounded open setes in $\mathbb{H}$. If you're concerned about that you should note that we could use the Cayley transform to turn our open sets into subsets of the unit disk and then transfer the conclusion back to $\mathbb{H}$" but I don't understand how this works...

Look where Cayley transform maps the boundary of $Q^+$ including infinity and see if you get a Jordan curve  (result is obvious for the half plane)

@Conrad Oh. So if the Cayley transforms are $\psi : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$ and $\phi : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{H}$, then if consider $\psi \circ h \circ \phi : \psi(Q^+) \to \mathbb{D}$ I can extend this to a homeomorphism on a boundary of $\psi(Q^+)$ because it is open, bounded and simply connected as the $Q^+$ (because that composition of functions is a conformal map, so a homeomorphism). And by applying the functions in the inverse way, we obtain that $h$ extends to a homeomorphism on the boundary. It's ok? Sorry for my late answer

Yes that's correct - the crucial fact is that $Q^+$ is transformed into a Jordan domain by the Cayley transform and that is seen as noted by looking where its boundary maps

Thanks @Conrad ! Great as always!
